# Invariant subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $\Phi: A\to A$ is a transformation of the set $A$. I want to understand what it means for a subset $B\subseteq A$ to be invariant under $\Phi$.

[Halmos](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/3098.html) states that this means $\forall b\in B (\Phi(b)\in B)$. Later on, in the same book, he characterizes an invariant subset $B$ as one satisfying $\Phi(B)\subset B$. I want to understand if these two are equivalent.

It seems to me that the statement $\forall b\in B (\Phi(b)\in B)$ is equivalent to $B\subset \Phi^{-1}(B)$, ($\Phi^{-1}$ here denotes the inverse image, which is always defined; not the inverse of the function) and not $\Phi(B)\subset B$. So my question is this:

> What does it really mean for a subset $B$ to be invariant under $\Phi$? is it $B\subset \Phi^{-1}(B)$ or $\Phi(B)\subset B$; or are the above characterizations equivalent for an arbitrary $\Phi$?

A tiny playing around with the definitions tells me that $A\subset B \Rightarrow \Phi(A)\subset \Phi(B)$, but in general the arrow doesn't go the other way around, i.e., $\Phi(A)\subset \Phi(B)$ does not, in general, imply that $A\subset B$. So the above definitions of invariant subset are not equivalent.

Comment: Instead of $\forall b\in B(\Phi(B)\in B)$, (which is equivalent to $B=\emptyset\lor \Phi(B)\in B$), I suppose you mean $\forall b\in B(\Phi(b)\in B)$ (which is practically the definition of $\Phi(B)\subseteq B$)

Comment: Indeed, I corrected the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are equivalent. Asserting that $A\subset B$ is equivalent to asserting that $(\forall a\in A):a\in B$. And asserting that $\Phi(B)\subset B$, in particular, is equivalent to $(\forall b\in B):\Phi(b)\in B$.

Answer (score 0):

$B \subset \Phi^{-1}(B)$ is equivalent to $\Phi (B) \subset B$. Both say the same thing: whenever $b \in B$ we also have $\Phi (b) \in B$.